# Get different events on setCompoundDrawables with differnet drawables

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable, android-event, compound-drawables

I have an `EditText` in which I'm setting `drawables` to the right of the `EditText`. I'm switching those `drawables` with different scenarios. I have `clearText` and `refreshIcon` as my drawables. These both are changing correctly but I'm not able to get separate events for both of my `drawables`. Here is what I'm doing for clearing text from the `EditText`:

```
String value = "";      

    final Drawable x = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear_text);
    x.setBounds(0, 0, x.getIntrinsicWidth(), x.getIntrinsicHeight());
    getUrl.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, value.equals("") ? null : x,
            null);
    getUrl.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (getUrl.getCompoundDrawables()[2] == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                return false;
            }
            if (event.getX() > getUrl.getWidth() - getUrl.getPaddingRight()
                    - x.getIntrinsicWidth()) {
                getUrl.setText("");
                getUrl.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I click `clearText` `drawable` it clears the text. It was nice and easy.

Now, I have another `drawable` i.e. `refreshIcon`, when on `EditText` `refreshIcon` is showing up it is not getting particular event for refresh purpose.

I have used the same code as of `clearText` for `refreshIcon`. I'm not able to print the `Log` when `refreshIcon` is `clicked/touched`.

What am I doing worong? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine 2 drawables into LevelListDrawable. Then use setLevel function to switch between them. You always can find  out which layer (drawable) is visible via getLevel method and do appropriate action.

Comment: Can you please explain me how. I have not heard about layerDrawable before. If you can explain me using code that will be really helpful.

Comment: I've a mistake ) You need [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList).

Comment: I think `LayerDrawable` will not work for me. See this statement `A Drawable that manages an array of other Drawables. These are drawn in array order, so the element with the largest index is be drawn on top`.  Largest index number, will have to change a lot for this. Can't we use the same method for two different `drawables`.

Comment: LevelListDrawable is what you need ) It allows to switch between drawables. Try it )